# 2 CSS-only columns same height

Tags: css

I've tried various methods I've found here and thru google searches to make my 2 columns the same height, but nothing is working for me. I must use CSS only (no more javascript on eBay!). The offending template is at http://sallymilo.com/sports/template2017b.html.
PS - this will be responsive, though I will add the code for that.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: add `.cont { display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; }`

Comment: you have display:table / table-cell that works fine since IE8, display :flex;  for newest browsers and display:grid too . Which of these did you try and where is going wrong ? you even have column-count + column-fill .... and if you want to deal with IE6, then this very old but solid method is still up to date https://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the background image kludge in the outer container since nothing else worked for me. And, it does work nicely!

Answer (score -1):

CSS only solution for columns that are the same size with different content is [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: First, this is wrong. Another solution is `display: table;` on the parent, `display: table-cell;` on the children. But second, this isn't an answer. Don't submit a link-only answer. Either give an actual code solution, or leave this as a comment on OP's post.

Comment: The table "fix" didn't work for me: the longer the content, the longer the column. The 500 padding bottom/-500 margin bottom thing didn't work either. The flex stuff confuses me! (And I don't want to spend the next 2 days deciphering it...)

Comment: @MichaelCoker Fair enough, I will leave a comment next time, I only left the link because OP didn't provide code. Also wasn't trying to say it is the ONLY answer. Just one of them, and IMO the best one